# Shiny app: Leaflet DrawToolbar: unable to remove ui from map when condition is not met

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have created an app utilizing the geoshaper package to allow users to select features found within a polygon created through the DrawToolbar plugin. However, if the user makes a selection polygon before data has been passed through the reactive filters, it crashes with the error code: “Warning: Error in .local: cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix”.

I thought it would be a good approach to not render the DrawToolbar unless a condition has been met, which works. The problem is when the condition is then removed, the removeDrawToolbar function does not work and is not removed from the map.

Any help would be appreciated.

The condition code is as follows:

```
observe({

if (!isTruthy(input$speccheck)){

  map <- leafletProxy("map")
  map %>% removeDrawToolbar(clearFeatures = TRUE)


} else {


map <- leafletProxy("map")
map %>% addDrawToolbar(
  position = "topright",
  targetGroup='Selected',
  polylineOptions=FALSE,
  markerOptions = FALSE,
  polygonOptions = drawPolygonOptions(shapeOptions=drawShapeOptions(fillOpacity = 0
                                                                    ,color = 'white'
                                                                    ,weight = 3)),
  rectangleOptions = drawRectangleOptions(shapeOptions=drawShapeOptions(fillOpacity = 0
                                                                        ,color = 'white'
                                                                        ,weight = 3)),
  circleOptions = drawCircleOptions(shapeOptions = drawShapeOptions(fillOpacity = 0
                                                                    ,color = 'white'
                                                                    ,weight = 3)),
  editOptions = editToolbarOptions(edit = FALSE, selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()),
  singleFeature = TRUE)

}})
```